# Why is Ruby's def +(other) method valid? What does "other" actually mean?

Tags: ruby

I'm practicing a Ruby program for 2D coordinate operations. Among them, the writing of `def +(other)` and `def -(other)` confuses me. I have the following three questions:

1. Why is the method name equal to the operator name?
2. Where are the parameters received? Passed from where?
3. Why is the parameter other called other, and what is its value and
   transmission process?

This is code

```
class Point
  attr_accessor :x, :y
  
  def initialize(x=0, y=0)
    @x, @y = x, y
  end

  def inspect # p印出(x, y)
    "(#{x}, #{y})"
  end

  def +(other)
    self.class.new(x + other.x, y + other.y)
  end

  def -(other)
    self.class.new(x - other.x, y - other.y)
  end
end

point0 = Point.new(3, 6)
point1 = Point.new(1, 8)

p point0
p point1
p point0 + point1
p point0 - point1
```

it will eventually print

```
(3, 6)
(1, 8)
(4, 14)
(2, -2)
```

Comment: In `point0 + point1`, `point0` is the receiver and `point1` is the argument. Most operators are actual methods in Ruby. See the docs for [methods](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.1/doc/syntax/methods_rdoc.html) for a complete list and some examples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1. Why is the method name equal to the operator name?

Why not? Why should the symbol used to *define* the operator not be the symbol used to *call* it? That's how we do it for every other method, after all: if I want to call `foo`, I define `def foo`.

The Language designers could have chosen any arbitrary name. But it just makes sense to have the name of the method be the same symbol that you use to call it. Can you imagine the confusion if the language designers had chosen, for example, the symbol `-` for the name of the method which corresponds to the `+` operator?

Other programming languages make different choices. For example, [in C++, the name of the function corresponding to the `+` operator is `operator+`](https://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.oper#tab:over.match.oper). [In Python, the name of the method corresponding to the `+` operator is `__add__`](https://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types). (More precisely, when encountering the expression `a + b`, Python will first try calling `a.__add__(b)` and if that is not implemented by `a`, then it will try the "reverse add" `b.__radd__(a)`.)

In C#, there is no method name which corresponds to the operator, [rather, there is an `operator` keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/operator-overloading) followed by the symbol corresponding to the operator.

If you want to know all the nitty-gritty details about how operator expressions are evaluated in Ruby, I recommend checking out Section 11.4.3 *Unary operator expressions* and Section 11.4.4 *Binary operator expressions* of the [ISO/IEC 30170:2012 *Information technology — Programming languages — Ruby* specification](https://iso.org/standard/59579.html).

> 2. Where are the parameters received? Passed from where?

It's not quite clear what you mean by this. A *parameter* is kind of like a "hole" or a placeholder in the method definition. This "hole" then gets filled in with an *argument* when you actually call the method. For example, here:

```ruby
def foo(a, b) a + b end
```

`a` and `b` are *parameters* (more precisely, *mandatory positional parameters*, they are *mandatory* because you have to pass an argument for them and they are *positional* because which argument gets bound to which parameter in the parameter list depends on the position of the argument in the argument list). You don't actually know what the result of this method will be because you don't know what `a` and `b` are. They are placeholders for values that will be filled in when you call the method:

```ruby
foo(2, 3)
```

Here, `2` and `3` are *arguments* (more precisely, *positional arguments*). The argument `2` gets bound to the parameter `a` because `2` is the first positional argument in the argument list and `a` is the first positional parameter in the parameter list. The argument `3` gets bound to the parameter `b` because `3` is the second positional argument in the argument list and `b` is the second positional parameter in the parameter list.

So, the code that gets ultimately executed *for this particular method call* is (replacing `a` with `2` and `b` with `3`):

```ruby
2 + 3
```

Please note: this is a simplified explanation. The mental model of replacing every occurrence of the parameter in the method definition body with the argument expression is a good first approximation, but it is not actually what Ruby does. In particular, that mental model I just described corresponds to the [*call-by-name* evaluation strategy](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_name), whereas Ruby actually uses a special case of the [*call-by-value* evaluation strategy](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_value) called [*call-by-object-sharing*](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_sharing).

You can observe the difference in this code:

```ruby
def bar(a) a + a end

bar((puts "Hello"; 23))
# Hello
#=> 46
```

In the "replace every occurrence of the parameter with the argument expression" mental model which corresponds to call-by-name, the code would look like this:

```ruby
(puts "Hello"; 23) + (puts "Hello"; 23)
# Hello
# Hello
#=> 46
```

and `Hello` would be printed twice.

However, with call-by-value and call-by-object-sharing, the argument expression gets evaluated before calling the method and the result of that evaluation gets passed in, so the actual code execution looks more like this:

```ruby
__fresh_variable_with_unspeakable_name__ = (puts "Hello"; 23)
# Hello

__fresh_variable_with_unspeakable_name__ + __fresh_variable_with_unspeakable_name__
#=> 46
```

If you want to know all the nitty-gritty details about how method arguments are evaluated in Ruby, I recommend checking out Section 11.3 *Method invocation expressions*, in particular Section 11.3.1 *General description* and Section 11.3.2 *Method arguments* of the ISO/IEC 30170:2012 *Information technology — Programming languages — Ruby* specification.

There is also some (unfortunately incomplete) information to be found in [The Ruby Spec Suite aka `ruby/spec`](https://github.com/ruby/spec/), in particular in [`language/def_spec.rb`](https://github.com/ruby/spec/blob/master/language/def_spec.rb) and [`language/method_spec.rb`](https://github.com/ruby/spec/blob/master/language/method_spec.rb).

> 3. Why is the parameter other called other, and what is its value and
>    transmission process?

The parameter `other` is called `other` because that is what the author of that piece of code chose to call it. They could have called it `a` or `b` or `x` or `y` or `foo` or `bar` or `i_dont_have_the_slightest_idea_what_to_call_this_parameter_so_i_am_just_choosing_something_totally_random`. If you want to know *why* the author of that piece of code chose to call it `other`, you would have to ask the author of that piece of code.

`other` is a somewhat popular name for the "other" operand of a binary operator definition, not just in Ruby, as you can see for example in the Python documentation as well. It does make sense if you read it out loud: in an Object-Oriented Programming Language like Ruby or Python, where operators are interpreted as being sent to one of the operands, one of the two operands of a binary operator will always be `self` or `this` and the "other" operand will be … well … the "other" operand. So, naming it `other` is just natural. In Ruby, this is codified in some Style Guides, for example the [Rubocop Ruby Style Guide](https://rubystyle.guide/#other-arg).

Comment: Deserves more upboats